# form 6i no popup for deleted record

Tags: oracleforms

Hi I am new to forms and now I am working on form 6i. When I delete a record and click on f4 or close a form without saving it a popup should come 'would you like to save the changes' that popup is not coming and form is getting closed. Can any one help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use the property "Form_Status" of the form to customize the message that you want to show to the user like this:

```
If (:System.Form_Status = 'CHANGED') Then
  -- Show customize message to the user.
End If;
```

This code go before each "Exit_Form()" that you having on the form.

Answer (score 0):

The default Forms functionality is as you stated that the an builtin alert should be displayed. This default functionality can though be overwritten in many different ways. The first things is to find if the form in question do have any custom logic for closing the form. You can start to check triggers Key-Exit and When-Window-Closed and the When-Button-Pressed of any Exit or Close button. The form is usually exited by builtin EXIT_FORM() and it have a commit_mode parameter that can have four possible values: ASK_COMMIT, DO_COMMIT, NO_COMMIT  and NO_VALIDATE. If your form is exited with values NO_COMMIT or NO_VALIDATE then the form will be exited without prompting the user and without committing pending changes. The ASK_COMMIT is the default value so something like this in the code for exit the forms should display the wanted alert to the user:

```
EXIT_FORM();
```